# Are all existing endpoints listed in documentation really still working for v4.9? (i.e. those not replaced by v1 so far)

Tags: php, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I have tried using old v4.9 endpoints that haven't been replaced by v1 so far such as:

```
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/reportInsights
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews
```

However, none of these endpoints work anymore.

I am using PHP client that had these endpoints missing, but using the official v4.9 library listed here: `https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/previousVersions` I have been able to reach some of the old endpoints such as reviews.

However they no longer return any data or data object is empty.

Anyone has experienced similar issues?

Comment: Also see reported issue here for similar info: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/issues/580

Comment: Why did they port accounts.locations.list, but then not accounts.locations.reviews?  So you have to interact with two totally different services to get locations, and then reviews?

Comment: I believe they are working on the `reviews` as well, but so far they have not migrated it.

Comment: got it makes sense.  just kind of annoying that they turn it off the old before finishing the new, but what do I know :)

Comment: I agree, I was also surprised to see this behavior. When I reported the issue to the PHP library devs, they just said that the Google GMB/GPB API devs had stopped publishing the old API manifest and therefore their library dropped it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v4.9 (not yet deprecated) endpoints such as reviews, insights etc. are working, but **the official library is broken and botched**.

I had to code a replacement using **Guzzle client** reaching to the endpoints  directly instead. So you need to code the API library yourself from scratch for these v4.9 endpoints as the official library does not work.

How to fetch reviews:

```
public static function listReviews($client, $params, $account, $location)
    {
        $response = $client->authorize()->get('https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/' . $account . '/' . $location . '/reviews', ['query' => $params]);
        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), false);
    }
```

How to fetch insights:

```
/** v4.9 working 02/2022 **/
    public static function reportInsights($client, $params, $account)
    {
        try {
            $response = $client->authorize()->post('https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/' . $account . '/locations:reportInsights', [
                \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $params,
            ]);
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $ex) {
            return $ex->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
        }
        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), false);
    }
```

How to prepare payload for insights:

```
$params = new \stdClass();
$params->locationNames = $account->name . '/' . $location->name;
$time_range = new \stdClass();
$time_range->startTime = Carbon::parse('3 days ago 00:00:00')->toISOString();
$time_range->endTime = Carbon::parse('2 days ago 00:00:00')->toISOString();
if ($force == 'complete') {
       $time_range->startTime = Carbon::parse('17 months ago 00:00:00')->toIso8601ZuluString();
       $time_range->endTime = Carbon::parse('3 days ago 00:00:00')->toIso8601ZuluString();
}
$params->basicRequest = new \stdClass();
$params->basicRequest->timeRange = $time_range;
$params->basicRequest->metricRequests = new \stdClass();
$metric_request = new \stdClass();
$metric_request->metric = 'ALL';
$metric_request->options = ['AGGREGATED_DAILY'];
$params->basicRequest->metricRequests = [
      $metric_request,
];
```

Note: if you are getting empty insights response, you have to check verification using new v1 API call such as:

```
$verifications = \Google_Service_MyBusinessVerifications($client)->locations_verifications->listLocationsVerifications($location->getName());
$verification = '0';
if ($verifications->getVerifications()) {
    $verification = $verifications->getVerifications()[0]->getState();
    }
```

Using official API client with an existing token (needs to be fetched via OAuth2):

```
$provider = new GoogleClientServiceProvider(true);
$client = $provider->initializeClient($known_token, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);
```